Error: Access to the path 'C:\Users\mnbvc\AppData\Roaming\y7_s\user_pc.exe' is denied during update process in C# application
I'm working on a C# updater application that downloads and extracts a ZIP file to replace older application files. The updater tries to replace user_pc.exe but throws the following error:
Starting updater...
Local version: 1.0.0.0
Server version: 1.0.0.1
Update found. Starting update process...
Downloading update...
Extracting update...
Replacing old files...
Error: Access to the path 'C:\Users\mnbvc\AppData\Roaming\y7_s\user_pc.exe' is denied.
Press any key to exit...

Code:
Here is the script I'm using:
namespace updater
{
    class Program
    {
        static string serverUrl = "http://199.218.1.105:8080/update/"; 
        static string versionFile = "version.js";
        static string zipFile = "userapp.zip";
        static string tempDir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "userapp_update");
        static string updaterDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; 
        static string appDir = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(updaterDir, ".."));
        static string userAppExe = "user_pc.exe"; // Name of user application

        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting updater...");
                string userAppPath = Path.Combine(appDir, userAppExe);
                string localVersion = GetAssemblyVersion(userAppPath);

                Console.WriteLine($"Local version: {localVersion}");

                // Step 1: Fetch server version
                string versionJson = new WebClient().DownloadString(serverUrl + versionFile);
                var serverVersion = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<VersionInfo>(versionJson);

                Console.WriteLine($"Server version: {serverVersion.Version}");

                // Step 2: Compare versions
                if (serverVersion.Version == localVersion)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No updates found. Closing updater...");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    return; // Exit if no update is needed
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Update found. Starting update process...");

                // Step 3: Close userapp.exe if it's running
                KillProcess(userAppExe);

                // Step 4: Download the new ZIP file
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);
                string tempZipPath = Path.Combine(tempDir, zipFile);

                Console.WriteLine("Downloading update...");
                new WebClient().DownloadFile(serverUrl + zipFile, tempZipPath);

                // Step 5: Extract files manually to the temporary folder
                Console.WriteLine("Extracting update...");
                ExtractWithOverwrite(tempZipPath, tempDir);

                // Step 6: Replace old files
                Console.WriteLine("Replacing old files...");
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(tempDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    string relativePath = file.Substring(tempDir.Length + 1);
                    string destPath = Path.Combine(appDir, relativePath);

                    // Ensure the destination directory exists
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(destPath));

                    // Delete old file if it exists
                    if (File.Exists(destPath))
                        File.Delete(destPath);

                    File.Copy(file, destPath, overwrite: true);
                }

                // Step 7: Cleanup temporary files
                Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up...");
                File.Delete(tempZipPath);
                Directory.Delete(tempDir, recursive: true);

                // Step 8: Restart the application
                Console.WriteLine("Restarting application...");
                Process.Start(Path.Combine(appDir, userAppExe));

                Console.WriteLine("Update complete!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                // Keep the console window open to read errors or messages
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        // Function to manually extract ZIP files with overwrite functionality
        static void ExtractWithOverwrite(string sourceZipFile, string destinationDirectory)
        {
            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(sourceZipFile))
            {
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    string destinationPath = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, entry.FullName);

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Name)) // It's a folder
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);
                        continue;
                    }

                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationPath));

                    // Delete any existing file to avoid conflicts
                    if (File.Exists(destinationPath))
                    {
                        File.SetAttributes(destinationPath, FileAttributes.Normal); // Reset attributes in case of 'read-only'
                        File.Delete(destinationPath);
                    }

                    entry.ExtractToFile(destinationPath, overwrite: true);
                }
            }
        }
        // Function to get assembly version
        static string GetAssemblyVersion(string exePath)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(exePath);
            string version = assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
            assembly = null; // Release the lock on the file
            return version;
        }

        // Function to kill a running process by name
        static void KillProcess(string processName)
        {
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(processName)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Closing {process.ProcessName}...");
                process.Kill();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }

        // Class for deserializing version.js
        class VersionInfo
        {
            public string Version { get; set; }
        }
    }
}


The error Access to the path 'C:\Users\mnbvc\AppData\Roaming\y7_s\user_pc.exe' is denied. occurs when the updater tries to replace user_pc.exe.
Things I’ve tried:

Ensuring the application is closed by killing any running processes of user_pc.exe before replacing the file.
Running the application as administrator, but the issue persists.
Checking file permissions, and the user has full access to the folder.

Can anyone suggest why this error occurs or any steps to resolve it?

Where (on which line of code) do you get the execption?

@KlausGütter I really don't know what line I have tried to drop the assembly using it to be null like this assembly = null; but did not help

Did you run your program in the debugger? Then you should know the line.

assembly = null will not release the assembly once it is loaded into an AppDomain. But you might use Fileversion.GetVersionInfo which will determine the version without actually loading the assembly.

This question is similar to: How do I get the version of an assembly without loading it?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
